# Postfix does not check "From:" address with sender_login_maps

Tags: postfix

I am trying to set up a postfix configuration where (virtual) users are allowed to only send with "From:"-addresses they own. So I put `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` into `smtpd_sender_restrictions`.

Using

```
query = SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='%s' and active=1;
```

in my `sender_login_maps.cf` I can send mails with any sender address I want, even something like `madeup@not_my_domain.com`.

However,

```
postmap -q "madeup@not_my_domain.com" mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/sender_login_maps.cf
```

returns nothing as expected.

Now if I change the query to

```
SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='notinthedatabaseforsure' and active=1;
```

I am not able to send any mails at all. So far so good. But the log says

```
postfix/smtps/smtpd[11683]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from...: 553 5.7.1 <user@domain.com>: 
  Sender address rejected: not owned by user user@domain.com; from=<user@domain.com> to=<user2@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.2.103]>
```

even if I try to send from `madeup@not_my_domain.com`. `user@domain.com` is the login name, `user2@domain.com` the recipient.

In a proper setup i would expect something like

```
postfix/smtps/smtpd[11683]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from ...: 553 5.7.1 <madeup@not_my_domain.com>: 
  Sender address rejected: not owned by user user@domain.com; from=<madeup@not_my_domain.com> to=<user2@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.2.103]>
```

So it looks like postfix uses the login name to search for the login name regardless of the sender address, which explains why I can send with any sender address using the query I mentioned first.

**Update:** I checked my sql logs and indeed, the MySQL server never sees `madeup@not_my_domain.com`. It only gets queries for the login address and the recipient address `user2@domain.com`.

Here are the smtps part from master.cf and my main.cf:

```
smtps inet n - - - - smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o tls_preempt_cipherlist=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  -o cleanup_service_name=submission-header-cleanup
```

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = all
mydomain = domain.com
myhostname = mail.domain.com
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination =
relayhost =


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_non_fqdn_recipient

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
 permit_mynetworks,
 permit_sasl_authenticated,
 reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
 reject_non_fqdn_sender,
 reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
 reject_unauth_destination,
 reject_unauth_pipelining,
 reject_invalid_hostname

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
 reject_non_fqdn_sender,
 reject_unknown_sender_domain,
 reject_unauth_pipelining,
 reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
 permit_sasl_authenticated

smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =   permit_mynetworks
                            reject_invalid_helo_hostname
                            reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
                            reject_unknown_helo_hostname

smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth

postscreen_access_list =        permit_mynetworks
                                cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access
postscreen_blacklist_action = drop
postscreen_greet_action = drop

postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 2
postscreen_dnsbl_sites = dnsbl.sorbs.net*1, bl.spamcop.net*1, ix.dnsbl.manitu.net*2, zen.spamhaus.org*2
postscreen_dnsbl_action = drop

virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/aliases.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/accounts.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/domains.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/relay_domains.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/sender_login_maps.cf


virtual_uid_maps = static:3000
virtual_gid_maps = static:3000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail

# Disable NIS lookup warning
alias_maps=hash:/etc/aliases

append_dot_mydomain = no
recipient_delimiter = +
```

Comment: migrated upon OP's request

Answer (score 0):

If a user with a login name `user@example.com` may only send as `user@example.com` you should use `reject_sender_login_mismatch` before `permit_sasl_authenticated`

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
    # ... skip ...
    reject_sender_login_mismatch
    permit_sasl_authenticated
```

This option [includes functionality](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/reject-authenticated-sender-login-mismatch-vs-reject-sender-login-mismatch-td20593.html) of both   `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` and 
`reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch`.

Moreover, check that your SQL query for a user returns his email (AKA login) for which postfix will run tests. If it just returns `1` or other "true" value it may not work as expected.

Comment: My SQL query does return the login name. Using reject_sender_login_mismatch in smtpd_recipient_restrictions does not work, too. Why would I have to put it in smtpd_recipient_restriction and not smtpd_sender_restrictions, anyway?

Comment: If you use email everywhere, your login name must be an email too.

Comment: You're right with `smtpd_sender_restrictions`

Comment: As you can see in my question, my login names are email addresses and I already had `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` in `smtpd_sender_restrictions`. I tried `reject_sender_login_mismatch` before but without success, too. Besides, only authenticated users are allowed to send mails anyway so using one or the other should not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put the `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` in the `smtpd_client_restrictions` field.

PS: Please note that `smtpd_client_restrictions` is different from `smtpd_sender_restrictions`.